# How to make ViewPager scrollable from the parent view?

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager

I was implementing the app tutorial which looks like this.

[image]

I made a nice and small `ViewPager` and placed it on the mock-up `ImageView`. The problem is that the `ViewPager` is not scrolled when I try to scroll it from elsewhere, say around the view pager indicators. This is so natural because there's no way that the `ViewPager` listens to touch event outside of itself.

1. How can I make `ViewPager` be scrolled when I try to scroll from elsewhere?

I've tried to [detect touch events](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html) on the parent of the `ViewPager` but I couldn't figure out how to relate `onFling()` or `onScroll()` to `ViewPager`'s scrolling.

2. If there's any better suggestion of implementing this kind of UI, what would be it?
3. Is there any tutorial or custom library similar to this?

Comment: You can use Gesture. On swapping gesture, change page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set a `View.OnTouchListener` for your outer `ViewPager` and check inside if you are on proper page which is displaying inner `ViewPager`. if inner `ViewPager` isn't on its first or last you might dispatch `MotionEvent` to second [dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)

```
outerViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            if(outerViewPagerAdapter.isCurrentPageHaveInnerViewPager() &&
                ! innerViewPagerAdapter.isOnFirstOrLastPage()){
                innerViewPagerAdapter.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
            return super.onTouch(event); //outer will get touch events
        }
   });
```

you might also adjust x/y touch cords in event before dispatching if needed